# How does the integration with Fitbit work for data generated on Apple Watch?

Tags: apple-watch, health.app

I'm hoping to replace my mom's Fitbit Alta with an apple watch. She's been a Fitbit user for years so we’d prefer to keep that data source

I browsed online and there's a lot of conflicting and outdated information. My questions:

### Can the AW sync steps to Fitbit? This is the biggest thing for her.

She doesn't care about Fitbit challenges. I would to hear with AW users who actually do sync their data to a Fitbit account.

Comment: I’ve edited this since we strongly prefer one question per question. Since you didn’t mention iPhone, we should assume you have an Apple Watch only and want to sync up data to Fitbit online or can we assume she has both an iPhone and a watch in this scenario?

Comment: She would have an iPhone and apple watch.

Comment: Cool. I shut down Fitbit quite a while back when it was clear to me they only wanted to sell their hardware and not participate in Apple Health, but perhaps their app has improved lately. I’d set your mum up apple health and see in 30 days if she even misses the Fitbit integration.